# Path separator char in python 2.4

Tags: python, path-separator

Just out of curiosity - is there another way to obtain the platform's path separator char than `os.path.normcase('/')` in Python 2.4?
I was expecting something like a `os.path.separator` constant...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That would be [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep).